What is a simple example of the use of a parametric variable to solve an equation other than use of r and theta?
One example that I know of is the solution of $x^{y} = y^{x}$ by parameterizing $y$ as $ax$: The solution falls out easily, giving $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a$.
Are there any other examples ?.
